# Does this diagram represent several LSTMs, or one through several timesteps?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, long-short-term-memory, papers, google

I'm trying to read [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144.pdf) paper describing Google's LSTM architecture for machine translation. It features this diagram on page 4:

[image]

I'm interested in the encoder block, on the left. Apparently, the pink and green cells are LSTMs. However, I can't tell if the x-axis is space or time. That is, are the LSTM cells on a given row all *the same* cell, with time flowing forward from left to right? The diagram on the next page in the paper seems to suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are the LSTM cells on a given row all the same cell, with time flowing forward from left to right?

Yes this is correct

The x-axis on this figure is basically the **time** axis. Essentially all pink boxes in the same row are **the same** LSTM cell, with different inputs from the same sequence. At each timestep, the cell takes an input and produces an output which is fed to the next layer. At the 8-th layer, the outputs over all timesteps are inputted at the same time to the attention layer.